# Can I stop Visual Studio spawning a web browser when I start debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugger

Can I stop Visual Studio spawning a web browser when I start debugging in VS2010?

I have the site open already, so I don't need Visual Studio to spawn another window/tab/etc :\

I'd love to be able to turn this behaviour off. I've googled plenty, to no avail.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 11):

For Web Application Project:

Right click on the project file in question, and open 'Properties'.  There, go to the 'Web' tab, and change the Start Action to 'Don't open a page.  Wait for a request from an external application.'  This will prevent it from spawning a page automatically, although you can still manually go to the page to debug it.

Answer (score 6):

For a "Web Site Project":

In VS2010, right click on the project node in the Solution Explorer then press Property Pages on the context menu. Alternatively, simply press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> to open Property Pages. Then press Start Options on left menu and select the "Don't open a page..." radio button.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're going to find a way to do this, as VS needs to spawn the browser process under it's control so that it can hook it and allow you to debug.  This way it also knows when you're done debugging (you closed that specific browser process).

From the other side: One day I was surfing along in my debug browser launched by VS (surfed away from the project I was debugging), and after using it to search with Google for a while eventually Google started complaining "We're sorry but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now." :)

Answer (score 2):

This is possible, and is done a different way depending on whether the application is set up as a "Web Site Project" or a "Web Application Project" in Visual Studio 2010.

For a Web Application Project:

> Right click on the project file in question, and open 'Properties'.
>   There, go to the 'Web' tab, and change the Start Action to 'Don't open
>   a page. Wait for a request from an external application.' This will
>   prevent it from spawning a page automatically, although you can still
>   manually go to the page to debug it.
>
> answered Dec 23 '11 at 0:09 Brisbe42 https://superuser.com/users/8627/brisbe42

For a Web Site Project:

> In VS2010, right click on the project node in the Solution Explorer
>   then press Property Pages on the context menu. Alternatively, simply
>   press Shift + F4 to open Property Pages. Then press Start Options on
>   left menu and select the "Don't open a page..." radio button.
>
> Answered by: Daniel Macias https://superuser.com/users/113770/daniel-macias

I'd like to mark both Daniel and Brisbe42 as having the correct answer. Perhaps the Meta can help sort this out. So here's their answers both included in one answer - both are correct, depending on context.